# In R, how do I delete rows in a data frame by column names of another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have one dataframe (df1) with more than 200 columns containing data (several thousands of rows each). Column names are alphanumeric and all distinct from each other.

I have a second dataset (df2) with a couple of columns where the first column (named 'col1')  contains rows with "values" carrying  colnames of df1.

But not for every row in df2 I have a corresponding column in df1.

Now I would like to delete (drop) all rows in df2 where there is no "corresponding" column in df1.

I searched quite a while using keywords like "subset data.frame by values from another data.frame" but did not find any solution. I checked, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041351/deleting-rows-from-a-data-frame-that-are-not-present-in-another-data-frame-in-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965945/copy-column-from-another-data-frame-to-based-on-row-names-from-a-different-data) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645212/subset-columns-of-one-data-frame-according-to-another-data-frames-rows) and some other places.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible example? [See tips here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) - use built-in data, or simulate data, or use `dput()` to share reproducibly.

Comment: But maybe what you want is `df2[df2$col1 %in% names(df1), ]`. It doesn't seem to matter at all that `df1` is a data frame, the only thing that matters is that you have a chracter vector of values you want to keep, and that happens to be `names(df1)`.

Comment: Thanks to @Gregor and Effel. You did the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3)
#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3

df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "c"))
#   col1
# 1    a
# 2    c
```

Keep rows in `df2` whose values are names in `df1`:

```
subset(df2, col1 %in% names(df1))
#   col1
# 1    a
```